# Geocoding Strategies - Python 2.x to Python 3.x

Tags: python, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get some basic access to the Google Maps API. In their [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client) they have an example shown on how to access it using Python:

```
import urllib2

address="1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA"
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s" % address

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
jsongeocode = response.read()
```

I converted it to python 3.4, but the data that I'm obtaining is not in a valid JSON format. An alternative route is to use BeautifulSoup, but I'm not trying to do anything complicated.

This is the code that I'm using with Python 3.4:

```
import urllib.request
import json

address="1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA"
url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s" % address

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as link:
    s = str(link.read())

print(json.dumps(s))
```

This is a snapshot of the data I'm receiving:

> "b'{\n   \"results\" : [\n      {\n         \"address_components\"
>   : [\n            {\n               \"long_name\" : \"1600\",\n
>   \"short_name\" : \"1600\",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are taking binary data and turning it into a string by wrapping it with `str`. The proper way to turn binary data into a string in Python3 is to `decode` it.

Thus, you should instead `decode` your results into a string before attempting to interpret them as json (Python3.4 example):

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as link:
    s = link.read()
    result = json.loads(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

But I also recommend giving [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) a shot because it can simplify these steps for you:

```
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get(url)
>>> resp.json()
{'status': 'OK', 'results': [{'types': ['street_address'], 'place_id': 'ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA', 'address_components': [{'types': ['street_number'], 'long_name': '1600', 'short_name': '1600'}, {'types': ['route'], 'long_name': 'Amphitheatre Parkway', 'short_name': 'Amphitheatre Pkwy'}, {'types': ['locality', 'political'], 'long_name': 'Mountain View', 'short_name': 'Mountain View'}, {'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political'], 'long_name': 'Santa Clara County', 'short_name': 'Santa Clara County'}, {'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political'], 'long_name': 'California', 'short_name': 'CA'}, {'types': ['country', 'political'], 'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US'}, {'types': ['postal_code'], 'long_name': '94043', 'short_name': '94043'}], 'formatted_address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA', 'geometry': {'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 37.4236854802915, 'lng': -122.0828811197085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 37.4209875197085, 'lng': -122.0855790802915}}, 'location': {'lat': 37.4223365, 'lng': -122.0842301}}}]}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the string be in double quotes for json? Also, any reason why `'status': 'OK'` shows up at the end for me?

Comment: 1) If it's a valid json string in Python, then the json library will know how to load it. Python doesn't distinguish between single/double quotes. The rules it cares about (for json) are whether keys/values are valid and whether it is formed correctly. 2) Dictionaries are not ordered in Python. There is no reason for status to show up at beginning or end.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Worked beautifully.